# binding a function to a list

Tags: r, nested

Where am I missing something?

```
FUN<-list()
make.FUN<-function(i) function(n) i+n
for (i in 1:3) FUN[[i]]<-make.FUN(i)
FUN[[1]](1)
```

If I check FUN assignment I get a reference to a nested function (as expected):

```
> FUN
[[1]]
function (n) 
i + n
<environment: 0x03adfad0>

[[2]]
function (n) 
i + n
<environment: 0x03ae0834>

[[3]]
function (n) 
i + n
<environment: 0x03ae0604>

>
```

Problem is that if I check:

```
> FUN[[1]](1)
[1] 4
>
```

when I expect 2! (clearly it is overwriting the last value)

On the other hand, if I manually assign for each element of the list:

```
FUN[[1]]<-make.FUN(1)
FUN[[2]]<-make.FUN(2)
FUN[[3]]<-make.FUN(3)
```

I get the correct answer:

```
> FUN[[1]](1)
[1] 2
> FUN[[2]](3)
[1] 5
>
```

I could workaround using do.call, but I can't realize what the interpreter is assuming in the first loop, or why is do.call mandatory in this case.
When I try:

```
FUN<-list()
make.FUN<-function(i) function(n) i+n
for (i in 1:3) FUN[[i]]<-do.call('make.FUN',list(i))
```

I get (as expected):

```
> FUN[[1]](2)
[1] 3
```

Any clue? (it only happens when using lists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is almost a copy-paste of the `force` example from the doc. You need to do:

```
FUN <- list()
make.FUN <- function(i) { force(i); function(n) i+n }
for (i in 1:3) FUN[[i]] <- make.FUN(i)
FUN[[1]](1)
# [1] 2
```

Relevant details from `?force`:

> force forces the evaluation of a formal argument. This can be useful if the argument will be captured in a closure by the lexical scoping rules and will later be altered by an explicit assignment or an implicit assignment in a loop or an apply function.